# Tomcat 7 WebSocket (JSR356) Examples error: WebSocket connection closed

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, tomcat7, websocket

I'm trying to setup Tomcat7 on Ubuntu 14.04 and run into the following issue:

- WebSocket (JSR356) Examples load but give the error: Info: WebSocket connection closed. - for everything.
- WebSocket Examples using the deprecated Apache Tomcat proprietary API - all work fine.

I've installed openjdk-7-jdk/openjdk-7-jre and set JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this by dropping the apt-get install and installed via official tar file.

Followed http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/install-tomcat-7-ubuntu-14-04/ for setting up Tomcat as a service.